# Non-blocking recv on Tokio mpsc Receiver

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am using Rust and Tokio 1.6 to build an app which can interact with an Elgato StreamDeck via `hidapi = "1.2"`. I want to poll the HID device for events (key down / key up) and send those events on an mpsc channel, while watching a separate mpsc channel for incoming commands to update the device state (reset, change brightness, update image, etc). Since the device handle is not thread safe, I need to do both things from a single thread.

**major edits below**

This is a rewrite of my original question. I've left my interim answer below, but in the interest of a more self contained example, here is a the basic process using `device_query = "0.2"`:

```rust
use device_query::{DeviceState, Keycode};
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio;
use tokio::sync::mpsc::{Receiver, Sender};
use tokio::time::timeout;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // channel for key press events coming from device loop
    let (key_tx, mut key_rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::channel(32);
    // channel for commands sent to device loop
    let (dev_tx, mut dev_rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::channel(32);

    start_device_loop(60, key_tx, dev_rx);

    println!("Waiting for key presses");
    while let Some(k) = key_rx.recv().await {
        match k {
            Some(ch) => match ch {
                Keycode::Q => dev_tx.clone().try_send(String::from("Quit!")).expect("Could not send command"),
                ch => println!("{}", ch),
            },
            _ => (),
        }
    }
    println!("Done.")
}

/// Starts a tokio task, polling the supplied device and sending key events
/// on the supplied mpsc sender
pub fn start_device_loop(hz: u32, tx: Sender<Option<Keycode>>, mut rx: Receiver<String>) {
    let poll_wait = 1000 / hz;
    let poll_wait = Duration::from_millis(poll_wait as u64);

    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        let dev = DeviceState::new();

        loop {
            let mut keys = dev.query_keymap();
            match keys.len() {
                0 => (),
                1 => tx.clone().try_send(Some(keys.remove(0))).unwrap(),
                _ => println!("So many keys..."),
            }
            
            match timeout(poll_wait, rx.recv()).await {
                Ok(cmd) => println!("Command '{}' received.", cmd.unwrap()),
                _ => (),
            };
            // std::thread::sleep(poll_wait);
        }
    });
}
```

Note this does not compile - I get an error `future created by async block is not 'Send'` and `within 'impl Future', the trait 'Send' is not implemented for '*mut x11::xlib::_XDisplay'`. My understanding of the error is that because `device_query` is not thread-safe, and `await`ing introduces the possibility of scope moving across threads, nothing may be awaited while a non-thread-safe object is in scope. And indeed, if I comment out the block around `match timeout...` and uncomment the `std::thread::sleep` everything compiles and runs.

Which brings me back to the original question; how can I both send and receive messages in a single thread without using `await` or the apparently forbidden fruit of `poll_recv()`?

Comment: `poll_recv` is the correct way to check a receiver for messages in a non-blocking way. It returns an enum Pending, Ready-with-a-msg, Ready-but-now-closed. Maybe you can clarify what about `poll_recv` is giving you trouble and show your code using it? https://docs.rs/tokio/1.10.1/tokio/sync/mpsc/struct.UnboundedReceiver.html#method.poll_recv

Comment: Ok, good to know I was on the right track, but then how do I go about getting the `Context` object that `poll_recv` wants?

Comment: @nlta not at all poll_recv is for task implementer like tokio to use.

Comment: @superstator use https://docs.rs/tokio/1.10.1/tokio/sync/mpsc/struct.UnboundedReceiver.html#method.recv

Comment: @Stargateur how would an unbounded channel help? That would remove a potential block on send when a bounded channel was full, but the recv still looks like it blocks.

Comment: 1 unbounded channel link is just random, that the link used by nlta take a bound channel if you wish if you have a complete [mcve] I would have take the good link 2 recv is async fn thus by convention not blocking... that BASIC of async, maybe you should read about it before write code. https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial

Answer (score 2):

After much hunting I found `noop_waker` in the `futures` crate which appears to do what I need in combination with `poll_recv`:

```rust
pub fn start_device_loop(hz: u32, tx: Sender<Option<Keycode>>, mut rx: Receiver<String>) {
    let poll_wait = 1000 / hz;
    let poll_wait = Duration::from_millis(poll_wait as u64);

    tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || {
        let dev = DeviceState::new();

        let waker = futures::task::noop_waker();
        let mut cx = std::task::Context::from_waker(&waker);

        loop {
            let mut keys = dev.query_keymap();
            match keys.len() {
                0 => (),
                1 => tx.clone().try_send(Some(keys.remove(0))).unwrap(),
                _ => println!("So many keys..."),
            }
            
            match rx.poll_recv(&mut cx) {
                Poll::Ready(cmd) => println!("Command '{}' received.", cmd.unwrap()),
                _ => ()
            };
            std::thread::sleep(poll_wait);
        }
    });
}
```

After digging through docs and tokio source more I can't find anything that suggests `poll_recv` is supposed to be an internal-only function or that using it here would have any obvious side effects. Letting the process run at 125hz I'm not seeing any excess resource usage either.

---

I'm leaving the above code for posterity, but since asking this question the `try_recv` method has been added to Receivers, making this all much cleaner.

Comment: This compiles, but  I suspect is not the intended way to use tokio channels. `poll_recv()` is a low-level function, not something application-level code should call (and try to come up with a context). Perhaps a [tokio timeout](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.22/tokio/timer/struct.Timeout.html) is the way to go - something like `Timeout::new(rx.recv(), Duration::ZERO).await`

Comment: Interesting, I will give that a shot

Comment: @superstator did the solution provided by 'user4815162342' work in your case? Interested to know.

Comment: @Nirmalya no, it didn't, though I don't remember why exactly. I've been using `try_recv` since with no issues